# Adding arrow at accordion

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was working on an accordion that when one of the tabs opens the other ones close. I wanted to add arrows on the side so that the arrows move when the accordion opens. So when it is closed is in this position [image: Closed position]   and when it is opened is in this position [image: open position arrow] . I also wanted to add a fade transition to the information that is shown after you click one accordion. Below you can find the HTML file and JS file of what i worked so far. I opened to suggestions if you have any other idea to make this better.

```
<dl class="accordion">
    
    <dt class="acc-d"><a href="">DESCRIPTION</a></dt>
    <dd class="acc">some text here</dd>
    
    <dt class="acc-d"><a href="">SHIPPING & RETURN</a></dt>
    <dd class="acc"> Some text here</dd>
    
    <dt class="acc-d"><a href="">REVIEWS</a></dt>
    <dd class="acc">Some text here</dd>
    
    </dl>

(function($) {
    
  var allPanels = $('.accordion > dd').hide();
    
  $('.accordion > dt > a').click(function() {
    allPanels.slideUp();
    $(this).parent().next().slideDown();
    return false;
    
  });

  
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make the chevrons to rotate 90 deg, like this:

```
.chevron-rotate {
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s linear;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear;
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
}

.chevron-rotate.down {
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

See [codepen](https://codepen.io/_miki_/pen/dyZZPpZ).